# Multiple audio sources to single ALSA device on different bit rates

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, mpd

I am building a audio streamer based on linux for high quality audio. I have several applications that i want to be able to have acces to the audio device at the same time. (like shairport-sync, roon and music player daemon)

I have found the *dmix* plugin for ALSA which makes it possible to have two stream of audio mixed into one audio device. However, *dmix* requires me to set the sample rate when defining the dmix device and i need the sample rate to be variable depending on the sample rate that is being outputted from the source.

Is there a plugin that allows for switching between inputs? Or am I missing something in dmix?

Comment: PulseAudio does this automatically, based on the first stream's sample rate.

Comment: I'd second using PulseAudio for resampling/transport stuff - much easier to set up.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **rate** (rate conversion) or **plug** (automatic conversion) plugins. See the [list of alsa-lib plugins](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html).

The configuration should be done in the alsa-lib configuration file located in the user's home (`.asoundrc`).

## Rate

> This plugin converts a stream rate. The input and output formats must be linear.

Example of use:

```
pcm.<name> {
        type rate
        slave <slave_name>
}
```

## Plug

> This plugin converts channels, rate and format on request.

Example of use:

```
pcm.<name> {
        type plug
        slave <slave_name>
}
```

---

## Example using dmix and automatic conversion plugins

```
# Overwrites 'default'
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dmixer"
}

pcm.dmixer  {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024 # Any unique value for Interprocess Communication
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        rate 44100
    }
}
```